# "послать его куда подальше"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая? Я помню, что вроде бы этy фразу пишут без запятой, но почему так? Это может быть сложно подчиненным, тогда запятая перед куда? Существует вариант "послать, и подальше", но "послать и куда подальше" не попадался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Послать его **куда подальше.**

Куда подальше ― цельное по смыслу сочетание,  соотносится с выражением  "куда-нибудь подальше".

Розенталь: [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146) не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

А что тут надо разделять? *Куда* и *подальше*? Попробуйте, кстати, заменить воображаемую запятую союзом И - ведь это можно делать.

Comment: Это может быть сложно подчиненным, запятая перед куда? Существует вариант "послать, и подальше",